# PHP Next/Previous Image Loop

Tags: php, image, function, loops

I have created an next and prev image link which works great. But I'd like them both to loop back to the beginning or the end. So say I have image101, image 202 and image243 once I hit image243 it will go back to image101.

I'd like same with previous, when I hit Image101 I'd like the link to go back to image243. (Self explanitory).

How would I go about doing this?

```
<?php   $sql = "SELECT id FROM albums WHERE user_id=".$user['id']." ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1";   $query = mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());    

while($album = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ ?>


                    <?php
                $photo_sql = "SELECT photo_id FROM userphotos WHERE photo_id > ".$_GET['pid']." AND photo_ownerid = ".$user['id']." AND album_id=".$album['id']." ORDER BY photo_id ASC LIMIT 1 ";

                $photo_query = mysql_query($photo_sql)or die(mysql_error());
                $photo_next=mysql_fetch_array($photo_query);



echo "<a href='photo.php?pid=".$photo_next['photo_id']."'>Next</a>";



                $photo_sql = "SELECT photo_id FROM userphotos WHERE photo_id < ".$_GET['pid']." AND photo_ownerid = ".$user['id']." AND album_id=".$album['id']." ORDER BY photo_id DESC LIMIT 1 ";

                $photo_query = mysql_query($photo_sql)or die(mysql_error());
                $photo_prev=mysql_fetch_array($photo_query);

                    echo " | <a href='photo.php?pid=".$photo_prev['photo_id']."'>Prev</a>";

}


?>
```

Comment: if(mysql_num_rows($photo_query)==0) { ... ORDER BY photo_id LIMIT 1 ...}  ... ORDER BY photo_id DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: Forgot to add in the most important part AND album_id=".$album['id']."

Which may or may not change things a little..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not do that from PHP? Instead of having all these superfluous MySQL queries, you can just get the photo ID's, and use PHP:

```
$photo_sql = "SELECT photo_id FROM userphotos WHERE photo_ownerid = ".$user['id']." AND album_id=".$album['id']." ORDER BY photo_id ASC"
$photo_result = mysql_query($photo_sql) or die(mysql_error());
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($photo_result)) {
   $photos[]=$row[0];
}
$total = mysql_num_rows($photo_result);

$current = 2; // whatever your position is in the photo array

echo '<img src="'.$photos[$current].'" alt="my image!" />'; // display current photo

$next = ($current+1) % $total; // modulo
$prev = (($current-1) < 0) ? $total : $current -1;

echo "<a href='photo.php?pid=".$next."'>Next</a>";
echo " | <a href='photo.php?pid=".$prev."'>Prev</a>";
```

Just to explain, we use a [modulo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) to get the correct next page. Getting the previous page speaks for itself: if we go below zero, use the $total number of photos.

Using it this way is much more efficient, database-wise, than all these greater-than-smaller-than queries.

Comment: But the user images are not uploaded in number order.. theirs no..1,2,3,4. Its like by whichever user uploads next..And that is the photo_id.
So its more like me user 1 has images 1, 3, 6 and 9
and my friend has images 2, 4, 5, 7 and 8.

Comment: That's why it says "position in the photo array" and not "photo id". It is the same thing though, because you maintain order and know the total number of photos. I've added a line of code to show you how to keep track of everything. Basically, you are not using "pid" directly anymore, you are using the array position. If you desperately want to use pid, you can use a temporary variable, like @position:=@position+1 for each row, use that for count, but display pid anyway.

Comment: can you explain what this variable does? $current = 2;

I have tried your code and it starts from zero. I don't know if I'm doing something wrong..Or I haven't put my question forward properly.

I have created an album which is album 22 with images inside so far with photo id 200, 201 and 204 and my friend has 203 in his own album of 19.. I've got the part where I click next photo_id to 204 from 201 over my friends image 203..Just I'm not getting the loop part.
I've tried your suggestion and its giving my next a id of 1 when I hover once clicked and I hover over prev it says 0.

Comment: The photo_id as soon as I load album 22 should be 200 next 201 next 204 next back to 200
Then same for previous.

Comment: As it says in the code, $current is the position in the $photos array, NOT the photo ID's themselves. The layout of the $photos would be something like array(0 => 200, 1 => 201, 2 => 204)--you can check this with print_r(). $current is the first number, $photo_id is the second. In your case, you want to link to 'photo.php?current=".$next."', if that makes it clearer for you to understand?

Comment: all I get when I hover over the link is 'photo.php?current=0 on the next button and 'photo.php?current=1 on the prev button!! I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a link to the first image like this:

```
$photo_sql = "SELECT MIN(photo_id) FROM userphotos WHERE photo_ownerid = ".$user['id']
$photo_query = mysql_query($photo_sql)or die(mysql_error());
$photo_first =mysql_fetch_array($photo_query);
echo "<a href='photo.php?pid=".$photo_first['photo_id']."'>First</a>";
```

And of course you can use MAX to get the last photo.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you your next entry, but also the first entry, which means if there is no NEXT it will give the first.

```
$photo_sql = "SELECT photo_id FROM userphotos WHERE photo_id > ".$_GET['pid']." AND photo_ownerid = ".$user['id']."  ORDER BY photo_id ASC LIMIT 1 ";
$photo_sql. = "UNION SELECT photo_id FROM userphotos WHERE photo_ownerid = ".$user['id']." ORDER BY photo_id ASC LIMIT 1 ";
```

then on previous do a UNION with ORDER BY photo_id DESC

Comment: You have an error on the second line.. And its not working. 

$photo_sql = "SELECT photo_id FROM userphotos WHERE photo_id > ".$_GET['pid']." AND photo_ownerid = ".$user['id']." AND album_id=".$album['id']." ORDER BY photo_id ASC LIMIT 1 ";
$photo_sql.  "UNION SELECT photo_id FROM userphotos WHERE photo_ownerid = ".$user['id']." AND album_id=".$album['id']." ORDER BY photo_id ASC LIMIT 1 ";